# Trying to get foraign key records where every connected records are deactive ( Laravel elequent query )

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 tables

```
Category's ( id, name )
Sub_categories ( id, key, value, category_id )
```

I'm trying to get all Category's whose all `sub_categories` are deactivated `( means are soft-deleted )`

let me explain more

i have `sub_categories` data like this

```php
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "key": "sub 1",
        "value": "sub_1",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category_id": 1,
        "key": "sub 2",
        "value": "1",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "category_id": 1,
        "key": "sub 3",
        "value": "1",
        "deleted_at": "2019-07-09 06:06:01"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "category_id": 2,
        "key": "sub 1",
        "value": "33",
        "deleted_at": "2019-07-09 06:06:01"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "category_id": 2,
        "key": "sub 2",
        "value": "33",
        "deleted_at": "2019-07-09 06:06:01"
    }
]
```

i want only `category_id` -> 2 ( where all `sub_categories` are `softedeleted` )

hear's category model code

```
    public function subCategory() {
         $this->makeVisible('deleted_at');
         return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory','category_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: can you put your model code of category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = Categories::doesntHave('subCategory')->get();
```

Comment: this code return when one or more subCategorys are deactivated .... i want when all subCategorys are deactivated ...

Answer (score 0):

you first have to define Relationship between `Categorys` and `Sub_categories` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships.
Then use query to get what you want https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Answer (score 0):

Get IDs of categories with sub categories:

`$categoryIdsWithSubCategories = SubCategory::get()->pluck('category_id')->toArray();`

Get categories without sub categories:

`$categoriesWithoutSubCategories = Category::whereNotIn('id', $categoryIdsWithSubCategories)->get();`